# Efficient way of computing 3x3 pseudoinverse in C on an embedded system

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-inverse

I have a 3x3 matrix of which I would like to build a pseudoinverse. What is the most efficient (in terms of computation speed) way to do that in a C code on an embedded platform:

- What data structure would you recommend to save the matrix (`struct`, 2D-array etc.)?
- What (efficient) functions/libraries are available for this purpose?

Comment: 3x3? brute-force!

Comment: You may want to disclose the particular platform you are coding to. I guess the algorithm may be tuned for a particular microarchitecture.

Comment: @Bob__, The hardware I use is STM32F405, but my question is more of a general character...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 3x3 inverse the memory shouldn't be a problem for an embedded system so you can you a 2D-array, and as for libraries I would write my own function.

Comment: Sorry, the efficiency in terms of computation speed, not the memory consumption. The inverse is needed for a controller, which runs with 500Hz. I just edited my question.

Comment: Then i don't think you will have a problem. The computation time won't have a big impact on the overall performance. If you have to calculate the inverse for an arbitrary NxN matrix, then that would be a problem, but for a 3x3 you don't have to worry about.

Comment: One way to go would be via the svd. For this google shows some hits eg https://github.com/ericjang/svd3